# Optimization via Simulation

Tags: optimization, matlab, nonlinear-optimization, simulation, integer-programming

I want to minimize an objective function $\hat{B_i}$ $i\in l$, which can be computed by a matlab code (assume $\operatorname{findB}(a, b, c)$ returns $B$. I have the following optimization problem:

$$\begin{array}{rl}
 \min & \sum\limits_{i\in l} \hat{B_i}(a_i,b_i, c_i) \\
 \text{s.t.} & \sum\limits_{i\in l} a_i \leq A \\
 & \sum\limits_{i\in l} b_i \leq B \\
 & \sum\limits_{i\in l} c_i = C \\
 & a_i,b_i \in\mathbb Z^+, c_i\ge0 \qquad \forall i\in l \\
\end{array}$$

How can I solve this in Matlab or in another platform? Note that I do not have a closed form expression for $B$. For a sample calculations, I can assume $A = 20, B=25, C=30$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are $ {a}_{i}, {b}_{i}, {c}_{i} $ have finite number of choices each? Or you just mean there is a vector $ a $? For the second option it will be easy. For the first one, it will be harder with some relaxation can be made.